# How to keep node app running?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, upstart, forever

I've finally finished converting one of my projects to use Node.JS, but now I'm having problems keeping my app running on the server :/ The problem is that if I close my putty session Node just stops.

I've done a lot of searching on this problem, and it seems that creating an `upstart` script and using the `Forever` module is the way to go.

I started googling and created this upstart script:

```
#!upstart
description "Loner NodeJS app launcher"
author      "me@me.com"

start on startup
stop on shutdown

script
    export HOME="/root"
    exec sudo node /home/jjmpsp/server.js >> /home/jjmpsp/server.sys.log 2>&1
end script
```

I then ran `start app` on the server last night and the server stayed running when I closed the putty session. All good.

However, I came on this morning and discovered that the Node app had stopped so I checked the `server.sys.log` file to see what was going on. It seems that the app ran fine until it eventually encountered this exception:

```
debug: client authorized
info: handshake authorized fziLHZA3Vo9i55eubvOq

events.js:48
        throw arguments[1]; // Unhandled 'error' event
                       ^
Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.
    at Protocol.end (/home/jjmpsp/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:73:13)
    at Socket.onend (stream.js:80:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:88:20)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:348:51)
```

Today I've been googling even more and discovered that Forever will actually restart a NodeJS app if it exits unexpectedly. I tried installing the module with `npm install forever` but I get this huge list of errors:

```
jjmpsp@alex:~$ npm install forever
npm ERR! error installing forever@0.9.2 Error: No compatible version found: node-fork@'>=0.4.0- <0.5.0-'
npm ERR! error installing forever@0.9.2 No valid targets found.
npm ERR! error installing forever@0.9.2 Perhaps not compatible with your version of node?
npm ERR! error installing forever@0.9.2     at installTargetsError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:424:10)
npm ERR! error installing forever@0.9.2     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:406:17
npm ERR! error installing forever@0.9.2     at saved (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/get.js:136:7)
npm ERR! error installing forever@0.9.2     at Object.cb [as oncomplete] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:36:9)
npm ERR! Error: No compatible version found: node-fork@'>=0.4.0- <0.5.0-'
npm ERR! No valid targets found.
npm ERR! Perhaps not compatible with your version of node?
npm ERR!     at installTargetsError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:424:10)
npm ERR!     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:406:17
npm ERR!     at saved (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/get.js:136:7)
npm ERR!     at Object.cb [as oncomplete] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:36:9)
npm ERR! Report this *entire* log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
npm ERR!
npm ERR! System Linux 3.8.4-x86_64-linode31
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "forever"
npm ERR! cwd /home/jjmpsp
npm ERR! node -v v0.5.11-pre
npm ERR! npm -v 1.0.106
npm ERR! Error: EACCESS, Permission denied 'npm-debug.log'
npm ERR! Report this *entire* log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
npm ERR!
npm ERR! System Linux 3.8.4-x86_64-linode31
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "forever"
npm ERR! cwd /home/jjmpsp
npm ERR! node -v v0.5.11-pre
npm ERR! npm -v 1.0.106
npm ERR! path npm-debug.log
npm ERR! code EACCESS
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/jjmpsp/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

What steps should I take to fix this? I'm completely out of ideas. I've been googling all sorts of technical details and I'm just not getting anywhere.

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Seems lite you are running an old version of node. Can you try and upgrade and see if it makes any difference. To see what version you run you can run process.version; in a node console.

I believe you also want to run the install with the global flag. npm install -g forever

Comment: jjmpsp@alex:~$ node
> process.version
'v0.10.5'

Comment: I've tried running 'sudo npm install -g forever' too :/ hmm

Comment: It's strange that the error log still shows '
npm ERR! node -v v0.5.11-pre' when I know I'm running v0.10.5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a painful few hours of re configuring everything, I think I have finally solved my problem! It looks like I may have had 2 versions of node or something! For future reference: If you are new to Node, be sure to install `nvm` to make managing node versions easier and you won't experience this problem :)

Answer (score 6):

1. First, you should focus on what is killing your node server. Forever isn't going to "fix" the problem. Every time node exits/restarts it *will* cause problems and your users can loose data. `upstart` or `forever` are just band-aids. (In fact, Upstart will restart your server, but it will give up if your server doesn't stay running.)

   The only long-term solution to find/fix each source of errors and write a regression test suite to verify that each previous problems has been fixed.
2. `start on startup` [will not work](https://serverfault.com/questions/279594/cant-get-upstart-script-for-node-js-program-to-start-on-startup#279966)
3. Your `forever` install broke because of permissions. Try `sudo npm install -g forever`
   Advanced:
   Your entire server setup should be scripted. That way you can set up a test/staging server that mirrors production. one simple way to do this is [Vagrant](http://vagrantup.com/). You can develop "locally" on the same OS that's on your server. And you can test things like "does `node` come up when I reboot?" or "if the server gets wiped out, can I re-create my server from the base OS?"

Comment: As you can tell, I'm new to all of this :p I have tried 'sudo npm install -g forever' but I still get the same error as before when installing forever. It's strange that the error log still shows 'npm ERR! node -v v0.5.11-pre' when I know I'm running v0.10.5. As for finding the source of errors, I have written my code so it handles errors efficiently as well, but it seems that the error I traced in the error log was caused by one of the built in Node modules. Do you have any suggestions on why forever still isn't installing? Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of research and bad solutions, I found pm2 (part of Keymetrics, recommended by Karlos) to be by far the best solution. You can find it here:

http://pm2.keymetrics.io/

Answer (score 1):

I think forever doesn't exits your nodejs app unexpectedly, It might be because of the mysql 'wait_timeout' parameter which is set to 28800 second (i.e 8 hours) by default.
If the nodejs app does not interact with mysql database for 8 hour, then the connection gets closed.
You have to set the wait_timeout value to 'MAX value'(i.e 365 days) or any other value as you required in the mysql db settings.

Link for the wait_timeout settings:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout

or

Add the following code in your code.
This code will ping the mysql db once in an hour and your connection will not break.

// MYSQL ping code starts

```
function keepalive() 
{
     conn.query('select 1', [], function(err, result) 
     {
         if(err) 
         return console.log(err);
         // Successul keepalive
         console.log("keepalive: "+ result);
     });
}

setInterval(keepalive, 1000*60*60);
```

// MYSQL ping code ends

You can also use the handledisconnect() code and handle the particular connection error in the code as given in the example below.

///Code starts

function handledisconnect() {

```
  log.info("handledisconnect()");
    // Reading config.json file for database connection
    var db_config = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(appRoot + "/conf.json"));

    conn = mysql.createConnection(db_config);

    conn.connect(function(err) {

        if (err) {

            log.error('error when connecting to db : ',err);
            // We introduce a delay before attempting to reconnect
            setTimeout(handledisconnect, 200);
        } else {
            log.info("database connected");
        }
    });

    conn.on('error', function(err) {

        log.error('db error : ',err);

        // handling the reconnection for 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST' error
        if (err.code === 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST') {

            log.error(err);
            setTimeout(handledisconnect, 200);
            handledisconnect();

        } else {
            log.error(err);
        }
        // handling the reconnection for 'EADDRINUSE' error
        if (err.code === 'EADDRINUSE') {

            setTimeout(handledisconnect, 200);
            handledisconnect();

        } else {

            log.error(err);
        }
        // handling the reconnection for 'ECONNREFUSED' error
        if (err.code === 'ECONNREFUSED') {

            log.error(err);
            setTimeout(handledisconnect, 200);
            handledisconnect();

        } else {
            log.error(err);
        }

    });

///**** ADD YOUR CODE HERE****////

}
handledisconnect();
/// Code ends
```

Answer (score 0):

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/479/keep-ssh-sessions-running-after-disconnection

do this:

`screen` // then press enter
`node server.js`

Answer (score 0):

From the logs what actually seems to be the problem in your case is your mysql connection. Whenever the mysql server closes the connection the node server would die. You can use a keealive or use connection pooling.

Answer (score 0):

Use keymetrics.io, it will restart your node application automatically if any issue occurs.

https://keymetrics.io